# Is there a way to restart the kubernetes pods using a command without using azure portal?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Is there a way to restart the kubernetes pods using a command without using azure portal?
As in azure portal it's able to perform this task, so i need a command to perform this.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-restart-kubernetes-pods-with-kubectl/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using `kubectl`. You will have to acquire your credentials using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-get-credentials). And delete your pods with `kubectl delete pod/<name> -n <namespace> --kubeconfig=<the file you acquired>`.